I am facing "Access Denied to Java Error" when attempting to run mule standalone server 4.7.2 in my local windows system
Error Log:
MULE_HOME is set to E:\mule_tests\mule1
MULE_BASE is set to E:\mule_tests\mule1
Running in console/foreground mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...
Found JAVA_HOME = E:\java\jdk-21\
The code page '65001' has characters coded on 4 bytes.
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.51
  Copyright (C) 1999-2022 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
    http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
  Licensed to MuleSoft Inc. for Mule Runtime Enterprise Edition

The value of property 'wrapper.java.command', '"E:\java\jdk-21" wrapper.working.dir=E:\mule_tests\mule1\bin wrapper.app.parameter.1= wrapper.app.parameter.2=  wrapper.app.parameter.3=  wrapper.app.parameter.4=  wrapper.app.parameter.5=  wrapper.app.parameter.6=  wrapper.app.parameter.7=  wrapper.app.parameter.8= wrapper.app.parameter.9=\bin\java"' contains unquoted spaces and will most likely result in an invalid java command line.
Unable to execute Java command.  Access is denied. (0x5)
    "E:\java\jdk-21" wrapper.working.dir=E:\mule_tests\mule1\bin wrapper.app.parameter.1= wrapper.app.parameter.2=  wrapper.app.parameter.3=  wrapper.app.parameter.4=  wrapper.app.parameter.5=  wrapper.app.parameter.6=  wrapper.app.parameter.7=  wrapper.app.parameter.8= wrapper.app.parameter.9=\bin\java" -version

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Advice:
Access denied errors when attempting to launch the Java process are
usually caused by strict access permissions assigned to the
directory in which Java is installed.
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Failed to launch the Java command.
backend pipe closed.
backend pipe closed.

I had JAVA_HOME  in c:/program files/java/jdk -21
I also had jdk 17 in the same java folder, I tried switching JAVA_HOME   between 21 and 17. Then i tried installing the java 21 in drive E and changed the JAVA_HOME   to the new location but I am still facing the same issue. I have no problem running normal jar files anywhere on my pc.
command:  mule in the bin folder

There are two errors in your setup:
wrapper.java.command must point to a Java executable
This is what the error message is telling. You are configuring wrapper.java.command to point to a directory, presumably the top of a JDK installation also known as JAVA_HOME. That is incorrect. It should point to the java executable file of that installation. Usually the executable java command is under the bin subdirectory and it is called simply java in Linux/macOS or java.exe in Windows.
It should like something like this: wrapper.java.command=E:\java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe
One of the versions of the JDK you are using is not supported by the Mule version
In particular for this case, even if you point to the right executable you'll have a second issue. The version of the JDK you are trying to use is not compatible with the version of the Mule runtime. Mule 4.7 it supports JDK 8, 11 and 17. JDK 21 is not supported. Always check the requirements for the specific Mule version in the documentation and use a supported JDK. Don't try random versions.
