Mule Runtime fail to start in Windows 11 with Java 17
When trying to start mule runtime am getting the following error. What is causing this and how it can be fixed ?
    D:\muletemp\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.8.1\bin>mule.bat
MULE_HOME is set to D:\muletemp\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.8.1
MULE_BASE is set to D:\muletemp\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.8.1
Running in console/foreground mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...
Found JAVA_HOME = C:\java\jdk-17.0.13.11-hotspot\
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.51
  Copyright (C) 1999-2022 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
    http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
  Licensed to MuleSoft Inc. for Mule Runtime Enterprise Edition

The value of property 'wrapper.java.command', '"C:\java\jdk-17.0.13.11-hotspot" wrapper.working.dir=D:\muletemp\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.8.1\bin wrapper.app.parameter.1= wrapper.app.parameter.2=  wrapper.app.parameter.3=  wrapper.app.parameter.4=  wrapper.app.parameter.5=  wrapper.app.parameter.6=  wrapper.app.parameter.7=  wrapper.app.parameter.8= wrapper.app.parameter.9=\\bin\\java"' contains unquoted spaces and will most likely result in an invalid java command line.
Unable to execute Java command.  Access is denied. (0x5)
    "C:\java\jdk-17.0.13.11-hotspot" wrapper.working.dir=D:\muletemp\mule-enterprise-standalone-4.8.1\bin wrapper.app.parameter.1= wrapper.app.parameter.2=  wrapper.app.parameter.3=  wrapper.app.parameter.4=  wrapper.app.parameter.5=  wrapper.app.parameter.6=  wrapper.app.parameter.7=  wrapper.app.parameter.8= wrapper.app.parameter.9=\\bin\\java" -version

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Advice:
Access denied errors when attempting to launch the Java process are
usually caused by strict access permissions assigned to the
directory in which Java is installed.
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Failed to launch the Java command.
backend pipe closed.
backend pipe closed.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .


looks like it's trying to find "java.exe" and it's only got a path/directory.  Maybe "wrapper.java.command" is set wrong?

Next time please use [code block] format for logs and code. This time I did it on your behalf.

This is the same issue than https://stackoverflow.com/q/78990547/721855. Your configuration is not pointing to the Java executable.
